# Need help in understanding this R script

Tags: r, matlab

I am very new in R so I would appreciate if anybody helps me to understand the following script so I can write in Matlab.
I am only interested in "R" method section of this script:
The following function is from `copula` package in R and it is for empirical copula:

```
> F.n
function (x, X, offset = 0, method = c("C", "R")) 
{
    stopifnot(is.numeric(d <- ncol(X)), is.matrix(x), d == ncol(x))
    n <- nrow(X)
    if (d == 1) 
        vapply(x, function(x.) sum(X <= x.), NA_real_)/(n + offset)
    else {
        method <- match.arg(method)
        switch(method, C = {
            m <- nrow(x)
            .C(Cn_C, as.double(X), as.integer(n), as.integer(d), 
                as.double(x), as.integer(m), ec = double(m), 
                as.double(offset))$ec
        }, R = {
            tX <- t(X)
            vapply(1:nrow(x), function(k) sum(colSums(tX <= x[k, 
                ]) == d), NA_real_)/(n + offset)
        }, stop("wrong 'method': ", method))
    }
}
<environment: namespace:copula>
```

Comment: there is [some documentation](https://github.com/cran/copula/blob/a4f35f8f09f1e1d97a3fcfcd6de11e61c77d5b40/R/empcop.R#L19:L21) for it. doesn't that help? also there is some c code in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Walk-Through

```
function (x, X, offset = 0, method = c("C", "R")) 
{
```

Function definition that takes two mandatory and two optional named arguments.

```
    stopifnot(is.numeric(d <- ncol(X)), is.matrix(x), d == ncol(x))
```

This makes an assertion (and exits if not true) that the return from `ncol(X)` is numeric (is it ever not?), that `x` is a matrix (2-dim array), and `x` and `X` have the same number of columns.

```
    n <- nrow(X)
```

Stores the number of rows for future use. (`nrow` is not an "expensive" function, but it does no harm to do it this way.)

```
    if (d == 1) 
        vapply(x, function(x.) sum(X <= x.), NA_real_)/(n + offset)
```

Branch on the condition that `X` has only one column.

The `vapply` function is iterating over each element of `x`, passes the number to the inner function, and captures each response into another vector. The `function(x.) ...` is an anonymous or immediate function, and in this case is called as many times as there are elements in `x`. The `NA_real_` is a way to tell `vapply` what type of variable will be returned; `sapply` would have worked as clearly (though not as quickly).

The resulting vector is divided element-wise by `n + offset` and is returned out of the overall function.

```
    else {
        method <- match.arg(method)
```

This ensures that `method` will be either `"C"` or `"R"` or the function will error-out.

The following, `switch`, is similar to a `select` or `case` statement, where it will do the first block of code if `method` is `"C"`, the second if `"R"`, and will stop otherwise.

```
        switch(method, C = {
            m <- nrow(x)
            .C(Cn_C, as.double(X), as.integer(n), as.integer(d), 
                as.double(x), as.integer(m), ec = double(m), 
                as.double(offset))$ec
```

Makes a call to a C library function named `Cn_C` with the provided arguments, and extracts the `ec` component from the return.

```
        }, R = {
            tX <- t(X)
```

Takes the transpose of `X`.

```
            vapply(1:nrow(x), function(k) sum(colSums(tX <= x[k, 
                ]) == d), NA_real_)/(n + offset)
```

(See my discussion above for `vapply`. This time it is iterating over a sequence of incrementing numbers from 1 to the number of rows in `x`.)

For the anonymous (inner) function, going inside-out, it starts by comparing the transposed `X` with the kth row of `x`, resulting in a matrix of booleans. The `colSums` in this case is merely counting the number of `TRUE`s in each column that come from that matrix-wise comparison. The outer `sum` is counting the number of these column-wise sums that are equal to the number of columns in `X` (as stored in `d`, earlier).

This vector is divided element-wise by `(n + offset)`, resulting in another vector.

```
        }, stop("wrong 'method': ", method))
```

Throw an exception if something else was provided to `method` in the function call.

```
    }
}
```

### Wrap-Up

You really should do some more study on `help(vapply)` if you are not very comfortable with Map-like functions on vectors. You might benefit from reading `help(match.arg)`, `help(switch)`. I think the other major functions (`nrow`, `ncol`, `t`) are clear enough.

You probably don't need to worry about the `.C(...)` call to a library function, since this function is kind enough to provide an *R*-native implementation as well. (Well, that's what I'm inferring, at least.)